# how to clear filtering, sorting and paging on a webdatagrid on client side?

Tags: javascript, datagrid, infragistics, webdatagrid

I have a webdatagrid which retains data on searching in text box. I have noticed when I filter/page/sort the data and before clearing any of these I make a new search then the new search results retains previous filter/page/sort condition. I am not clearing it before reloading the page. I have search method on client side and I am using following code which does not work:

```
function btnSearch_click(sender, evntArgs){
     var grid = $find('<%= grid1.ClientID %>');
     grid.get_behaviors().get_filtering().clearColumnFilters();
     grid.get_behaviors.get_sorting().clearColumnSorting();
     grid.get_behaviors.get_paging().clearPaging();
}
```

This code is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my grid loads on pressing the search button. I used the following on the server side:

```
if (search == "True")
{
    var filtering = grid1.Behaviors.Filtering;
    grid1.Behaviors.Sorting.SortedColumns.Clear();
    grid1.Behaviors.Paging.PageIndex = 0;
    grid1.Behaviors.Filtering.ClearBehaviorColumnInfo();
    grid1.Behaviors.Filtering.ColumnFilters.Clear();
    filtering.FilterType = Infragistics.Web.UI.GridControls.FilteringType.ExcelStyleFilter;
    grid1.Behaviors.Filtering.ApplyFilter();
}
```

I wanted to implement excel style filter and Infragistics had no way to reproduce excel filter after clearing it I had to apply row type filter first and then change the filter type to excel type.